# What aircraft has a sustained bright orange light visible at night/early morning?

Tags: aircraft-identification, aircraft-lighting

This morning around 6 a.m. in Durham, N.C. I was sitting on my porch and saw a bright orange light, I thought it was Mars it was so orange, but it was very bright.  After looking at it for a moment it briefly ascended and disappeared.  Now, there is no cloud cover, I just double-checked. What could this be?

My central heating system was also at a lull and making a weird noise I havn't heard it make and it started right back up when the thing disappeared.  Am I wiggin?  Did I see a UFO?

Edit: The direction of the light was southwest and it was not very high above the horizon, I am unable to give degrees as I don't know how, wish I did.  I did not have to look up, I was sitting as well and saw it quite easily without tilting my head.

Comment: "Did I see a UFO?" -> Yes, since you could not identify that flying object, you did indeed (by definition) see an Unidentified Flying Object (UFO). But most likely not an alien one xD

Comment: Lol, I guess that is why I want to see if anyone else may be able to point me in a direction of what it could be.  But yes, indeed, so far it's a UFO per definition :)  Thanks, I havn't seen anything like this before.   I mean, a single parachute flare perhaps?  It was pretty high up though.

Comment: Which direction was the light and estimated how high above horizon in degrees?  Question could be improved by this info.  PS a parachute flare would not be expected to ascend.

Comment: Could've been an older aircraft with the landing lights on - they tend to use halogen bulbs, rather than modern, white LEDs which can appear orange if conditions are right. The "ascending" could've been your perspective as it passed overhead (maybe you didn't hear it fly over because of your heating?)

Comment: The direction of the light was southwest and I am unable to quantify how high above the horizon in degrees as I am unsure how to do so.  It was not very high though, I did not have to tilt my head up at all, and I was sitting. I was also thinking of landing lights but the ascent doesn't make sense.  Are there also lights that go on after taking off? I believe so... That being said, I saw no blinking lights whatsoever in the presence of this large bright orange light.  Thank you for your feedback and questions.

Answer (score 6):

If it was early morning you probably saw an aircraft which reflected the morning sun. Even if the sun has not yet come up on the ground, it may already illuminate aircraft at altitude. As soon as it is no longer illuminated, for example because of a cloud of simply the horizon between the sun and the aircraft, the glow will no longer be visible, and the lighting conditions may be such that the entire aircraft may no longer be discernible to the naked eye.

As to your central heating, try diy.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Re "As to your central heating, try diy.stackexchange.com."  +1 for most unusual answer ever given on ase...

Comment: However 6 AM is a long time before sunrise this time of year...

Comment: @quietflyer Dawn at Durham is around 6.55 which is close enough for me.

Comment: I think you are spot on. I see the same phenomena in the hills to the east of me when the sun sets. Usually 15 minutes before to 15 minutes after sunset depending on how high up the building are. I”m guessing it’s the sun reflecting off of the windows.

Comment: That's the way to see satellites or the space station, just before sunrise or after sunset. That leaves plenty of time to fix the heating.